# How to setup Play Slick with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

I'm trying for the first time to setup a Play project and I already got stuck!
In fact when I run the application I get this exception as soon as I try to call "http://localhost:9000/":

```
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: db - Connection is not available, request timed out after 1004ms
```

I also get this in the logs every 2 seconds:

```
[error] c.z.h.p.PoolBase - db - Failed to execute isValid() for connection, configure connection test query. (Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(int) is not yet implemented.)
```

**This is what I did:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Code side I just created a class DAO to add, remove and list the records for the user table and called the "add" method from the controller.

I hope I gave enough details

Comment: This sounds like a connection leak! Can you also show us how you use the DB Connection object to make the database calls?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added the part where I do the calls to the db

Comment: Did you try logging the calls from Slick? logger.scala.slick=DEBUG

Comment: I tried now but nothing changed because I noticed that the exception is triggered before everything, even before the controller is called

Comment: Can you perhaps avoid using play-slick library? Have a look at my answer!

Comment: I'm trying this solution.. I'll write here how it goes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the final solution using the Play Slick library, configuring it in this way:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can see the versions of Slick and Play used in the PlaySlick library from the table in [this page](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick)

Comment: Grazie tantissimo!!! That really helped to configure play slick postgres connection.

Answer (score 2):

I would try avoiding using the Play-Slick library and use the Slick libraries as such! For some examples on how this could be done, have a look here in one of my projects:

https://github.com/joesan/plant-simulator/tree/master/app/com/inland24/plantsim/services/database

Over there I have used Slick as a dependency to my project directly and I'm not using the play-slick dependency.